# Proper implementation of changing ListView data with CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor, listactivity

I have a ListView populated via a CursorAdapter.  I give my user the ability to alter the data in the list.  For example, the user can mark a row as being unread (the data are messages).

Suppose my user marked a row unread.  Would a proper implementation mark the row in the database as read and then requery the Cursor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would a proper implementation mark the row in the database as read and then requery the Cursor?

Yes, that's the right answer. The `requery()` will trigger an automatic update of your `CursorAdapter`, which will trigger an automatic update of the `ListView`, which will trigger an automatic smile from the user. :-)

**UPDATE**

The `requery()` method is deprecated. A better approach nowadays is to run a query to get a fresh `Cursor`, then use `changeCursor()` or `swapCursor()` on your `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: I just didn't know how heavy requery() was and if it was the proper thing to do for changing 1 small piece of data

Comment: @Andrew: You don't have a choice. A `Cursor` is immutable except via `requery()`, so there's no other way for you to get the data in there. Your only alternative would be to schlep all the `Cursor` data into some other data structure, and that would be slow and painful.

Answer (score 0):

If the cursor is back by a ContentProvider and the ContentProvider issues correct notifications, the CursorAdapter will automatically refresh itself i.e. without the need to issue an explicit requery().