# Updating a ListView with frequently changing data in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

The question posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639369/proper-implementation-of-changing-listview-data-with-cursoradapter) thread asks how to update a ListView when the data has changed. It assumes, however, that the data that is modified in a ListView is stored in a database. Therefore, the ListView UI can be updated by simply calling requery() after the changes have been committed to the database.

What should one do when modified data of a ListView is **not** stored in a database?

For example, if each item in a ListView is showing the distance to a particular landmark based on the user's current GPS coordinates, what is the correct way to update the view with the updated distances as the user moves about?  Should the distances simply be stored in the database as a matter of convenience, so that requery() will update the UI? This does not seem like the correct approach if it is not necessary to persist (frequently changing) GPS data.

Edit: To clarify, I'd specifically like to address the situation where some of the data is stored in a database (the coordinates of the landmarks, for example), however, the frequently changing data is computed on the fly (e.g., the distances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayAdapter can be used instead of CursorAdapter.

The notifyDataSetChanged() method can be used to tell the ListView to refresh itself by requerying the ArrayAdapter assigned to it.

Comment: I should clarify that some of the data in the ListView does need to be stored in a database (for example: the landmark GPS coordinates in the example above). Should I therefore convert the data returned by the database query into an array and use ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `ArrayAdapter` instead of `CursorAdapter` (which is used to populate a ListView based on cursor > database query)

[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

You should update the array data storing your coordinate data. When it changes call [`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to have your list updated with the latest array data

Hope that helps